# How to save partial data in a separate model and then query checks if that data exists?

Tags: django-rest-framework

My data consists of some products, which are defined in `FdProduct` model:

```py
# models.py:
class FdProduct(models.Model):
   product_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.product_id
```

```py
# serializers.py:
class FdProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   product_id = serializers.RegexField(regex='^\d{3}\.\d{6}$', max_length=10, min_length=10, allow_blank=False)
   name = serializers.CharField(min_length=6, max_length=50, allow_blank=False)

   class Meta:
      model = FdProduct
      fields = '__all__'
```

For each existing product I can prepare a configuration and save it using a model called `SavedConfiguration`:

```py
# models:
class SavedConfiguration(models.Model):
   saved_conf_id = models.CharField(max_length=13, primary_key=True)
   saved_config = models.TextField()
   product = models.ForeignKey(FdProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
   session_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, default=0)
   creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.saved_conf_id)
```

```py
# serializers.py:
class SavedConfigurationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   saved_conf_id = serializers.RegexField(regex='^sc\d{2}', allow_blank=False)
   saved_config = serializers.CharField(min_length=6)
   session_id = serializers.RegexField(regex='^se\d{2}', allow_blank=False)

   class Meta:
      model = SavedConfiguration
      fields = '__all__'
```

By connecting the `SavedConfiguration` with `FdProduct` model with use of ForeignKey I ensure that a product exists in the database when I configure it and want to save the configuration.

I'd like to introduce two things more: the first one would be a model for storing just a `product_id` and an array containing all `saved_conf_id`s for that product:

```py
# models.py:
class ConfigOptions(models.Model):
   product_id = ...
   saved_conf_id = [...]
```

For example, if I configured a couple of times two products, *Product One* and *Product Three*, I may have data like this:

```
- Product One:
   - C_ID_0023
   - C_ID_0025
   - C_ID_0032

- Product Three:
   - C_ID_0149
   - C_ID_0273
```

My question now is, how to construct such model and serializer for which records are created (copied) into `ConfigOptions` model table each time `SavedConfiguration` is saved?

Second question: I'm thinking about creating another model, say `ConfigPresenceCheck`, which would receive POST requests and based on that would check if saved product configurations exist (so, fetching them from `ConfigOptions` or returning 404), and if they exist, would return them together with all parameters from `SavedConfiguration` (e.g. *saved_config*, *session_id*, etc.).

Please give me directions how to build such models. I'd also appreciate some good tutorials related to 
constructing Django models.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use many to many fields instead of foreign key, from my understanding many products can have many saved configurations and vice versa, at database level many to many fields are stored by creating a table any way.